# origin of sckikit learn datasets

Tags: reference, scikit-learn, dataset

One of my students is using the diabetes dataset from the scikit-learn package to familiarize herself with machine learning. She needs to write a report about this and has come to me asking where this data originally comes from. The only sources we found do not specify the original publication or cohort study that may have generated this data. Does anyone know where this data comes from?

References we found:

1. [The scikit-learn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_diabetes.html)
2. [Least Angle Regression, by Efron et al. 2003](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ftp/lars.pdf) (Table 1)
   [edit] This paper is cited as a reference in the documentation, but it doesn't include any information about who sampled the dataset (original scientific publication), which cohort from what country it was. There is no substantial indication that this data wasn't made up. Is this data from real patients or is it an entirely artificial dataset? Getting to learn how to use machine learning with scikit-learn is nice, but it's frustrating not to know where the training sets come from.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/~boos/var.select/diabetes.html) can help. But this question is off-topic for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [dataset doc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/index.html#diabetes-dataset)

> Source URL: http://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/~boos/var.select/diabetes.html

Comment: Thanks, actually I found this as well, and the only reference they give is "From Bradley Efron, Trevor Hastie, Iain Johnstone and Robert Tibshirani (2004) "Least Angle Regression," Annals of Statistics", which was included in my original post. We read that paper but it doesn't tell us who sampled the dataset (original scientific publication), which cohort from what country it was, no substantial indication that this data wasn't made up. Is this data from real patients or is it an entirely artificial dataset?